# How to pass arguments to callable method specifically for register_shutdown_function?

Tags: php, oop, arguments, callable

I have method, in this method may be happened fatal error, for catching this error I make this

```
class a {


    function shutDownFunction() { 
        $error = error_get_last();
        if ($error['type'] == 1) {
            echo "this is fatal error";
        } 
    }


    function terribleFunction () {
        register_shutdown_function(array($this,'shutdownFunction'));


        // here is code, wich may causes fatal error

    }


}
```

Okay, this understand, but I need pass argument from `terribleFunction` to `shutDownFunction`. How to make this?

Comment: Maby you are looking for [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Comment: Also, you can't catch fatal errors. They are fatal for a reason.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First you need to specify that `shutDownFunction` should accept a parameter.

`function shutDownFunction($var)`

Then you can call `register_shutdown_function` as so

`register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'shutdownFunction'), $myVar);`

Documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) and there are examples in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use one register_shutdown_function and not use it just inside a method to catch errors in that method. For error catching use a try, catch, finally block

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0):

You can check [register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function) documentation. There is a second optional argument `parameter` which is passed to your `shutDownFunction()`. This function you can define like this:

```
function shutDownFunction($args) {
   //do whatever you want with $args
}
```